# Header flickering and freezing issue with material table (implemented with react window + react window infinite loader)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-window

I have implemented an Infinite scrolling table with react-window (based on [#60](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window/issues/60#issuecomment-588397239)) and material UI.

The table seems to be fulfilling the main objective but there are few issues with it -

1. header is not sticking on the top in spite of having styles in place (`stickyHeader` prop).
2. header is flashing/flickering while scrolling quickly towards up direction.
   [Steps to reproduce - scroll 50% down then do fast scroll up and observe the header movement ].

Here's the codesandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-with-table-elements-forked-huti6?file=/src/index.tsx:514-542

Comment: The flickering is a feature, not a bug...... What's happening is `react-window-infinite-loader` is displaying only the data currently visible in the viewport, in order to speed up load times. As you scroll up, new data is loaded, and the old data is removed, but if you scroll very fast it can't keep up. Take a look at what's happening inside `.MuiTableBody-root`

Comment: @EliezerBerlin what you said is correct, there are lots of add-delete in the TBody section so flickering there is fine but there are no changes in the header section so it supposed to be freeze, right?

Comment: Again, it's from `react-window-infinite-loader`. The table moves around using position:absolute and `top`. The real cause of the flickering is that the `top` attribute on the `table.MuiTable-root` isn't fast enough to keep up with your scrolling.

Comment: Though you might also want to add the css: `table-layout:fixed;` to your table so that the width of the header isn't determined by the width of the *currently visible content*.

Comment: Tried `table-layout: fixed;`, didn't see any difference.

Comment: Well, in the demo, the width of every column is identical, so there's not much difference. But when you get to a real site, your data is going to have different widths, and that might cause the width of columns to change if you don't use table-layout:fixed. (It's not going to affect the flickering.)

Comment: Understood, that's a good point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use default value for `TableContainer` `overflow-x` and the sticky header should work

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tableContainer: {
    overflowX: "initial"
  }
})

function Inner({ children, ...rest }, ref) {
  const { header, footer, top } = useContext(VirtualTableContext)
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TableContainer classes={{root: classes.tableContainer}} {...rest} ref={ref}>
    ...
```

[image: Edit React-Window with table elements (forked)]

Comment: The header is at the top, but it (and everything else) is still flickering when I scroll upwards quickly.

Comment: Yup... It is still flickering while scrolling up quickly towards up.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your implementation, the [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#virtualized-table) have a working example of a virtualized table which achieves what you're looking for using `react-virtualized`. That is, the header is sticky and there is no flashing/flickering of the header during scroll.

Below is a codesandbox
containing a working example to reflect your desired layout.

[image: Material demo (forked)]

Comment: react-window is a complete rewrite of react-virtualized and It is much lighter and faster than react-virtualized. The main problem here is due to the infinite loader, It is causing header flickering so changing the library won't make any difference. There won't be a header issue in the plain virtual table by react-window.

Comment: @DevAKS Yes, agreed that there won't be a header issue if you use the plain virtual table by react-window. In fact, there is a nice [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mk3qwpl4l) of such a solution available. Given that the full functionality of react-window-infinite-loader is not implemented in your solution (i.e. you do not simulate the loading of remote data), why do you need a solution that includes react-window-infinite-loader?

Answer (score 0):

**First about the `react-window`:** The Scollbars in the `react-window` are for the `outercontainer` not for `InnerContainer`. Now don't try to replace the outer container itself, unless you want to handle everything yourself. All the scroll events a few more things are attached to the `outercontainer`.

**Think of it like outer container decides/takes the size and the larger inner container gets scrolled inside it.**

Now looking at your case I assume you are trying to make the table behave like any other grid where headers are fixed and content is scrolled if it's getting overflow. your table header is way lower in the element hierarchy than the inner container, so no way you can write any simple css (or js logic) to achieve in current hierarchy.

**that's why even though you have set the `stickyheader` for the `MaterialUI` `table`, it won't stick. Cause your whole table (`MaterialUI` `table`) is getting scrolled inside the outer container of `react-window`.**

I would suggest you to move your table header outside of the `react-window` and only place the rows in the `react-widow`. that's the way it's suppose to behave (i.e. react window treats everything in it as scrollable content). See one of the **presentation** below:

[image: ReactWindow]

A little tip on redesigning of your `table` (guess the alignment can be improved by additional css)

[image: header outside of reactwindow]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. We cannot put `react-window` on rows only as it is a violation of material UI rules, you cannot add extra div inside TableBody. Also, I tried your suggested changes, It is not working and It is giving warning (`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <thead> cannot appear as a child of <div>.`)

Comment: @DevAKS so you are just concerned about the rule of MaterialUI not react-window. you have out the materil UI table at the wrong hierarchy level to begin with. You can design your component as your need. The idea is, don't think the header as html table header (th) think of it as normal header (collection of DIVs). which is also the cause of your error, i.e. table header outside of a table. just make it outside of the react-window. I suppose the table footer will have same issue. more precisely only TableBody should be inside the react-window.

Comment: @DevAKS btw equally curious to know which rule are you breaking by designing something like <table><TableHead></TableHead><TableBody> {react-window}</TableBody></table>

Comment: Well, I am concerned about the rules as a violation of these rules generates a warning and I can't have such code in production that generates a warning.

Comment: Also, I have provided codesandbox link there you can check the console, it is generating zero warning/errors.

Comment: @DevAKS the warning is about the <tableheader> is being used without the table. I was just giving you a tip on design. in my view, you should just create {header} {body} and  {footer} inside the VirtualTable compoent and just remove the inner component completely. and in the VirtualTable compoent the react-window should be used to wrap the {tablebody}.